# Does intersection of unions of decreasing subsets equal union of intersections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let

- $X$ be a set,
- $I$ be an ordinal number (possibly infinite),
- $A_i \subset X$ for each $i \in I$,
- $A_i \supset A_j$ for each $i, j \in I$ such that $i < j$; i.e. $A$ is a decreasing (transfinite) sequence,
- $B_i$ have requirements similar to $A_i$.

Does it hold that

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} (A_i \cup B_i) = (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \cup (\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i)$$

?

#### Holds when $I$ is a successor ordinal.

Suppose $I$ is a successor ordinal, and $I_-$ is its predecessor. Then

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} (A_i \cup B_i) = A_{I_-} \cup B_{I_-} = (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \cup (\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i),$$

and the result holds.

#### Superset when $I$ is a limit ordinal.

Suppose $I$ is a limit ordinal. Then clearly

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} (A_i \cup B_i) \supset (\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i) \cup (\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i)$$

The unclear case is then the $\subset$ direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in X$.

Suppose there exists $j \in I$ such that $x \not\in A_j$. Then $x \not\in A_i$ for each $i \geq j$. Therefore
\begin{aligned}
{} & x \in \bigcap \{A_i \cup B_i : i \in I\} \\
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{A_i \cup B_i : i \in I \land i \geq j\} \\
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{B_i : i \in I \land i \geq j\} \\
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{B_i : i \in I\} \\
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{A_i : i \in I\} \cup \bigcap \{B_i : i \in I\}.
\end{aligned}
Suppose there exists $j \in I$ such that $x \not\in B_j$. Then a similar derivation as above holds.

Suppose $x \in A_i \cap B_i$ for each $i \in I$. Then
\begin{aligned}
{} & x \in \bigcap \{A_i \cup B_i : i \in I\} \\    
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{A_i \cap B_i : i \in I\} \\    
\iff & x \in \bigcap \{A_i : i \in I\} \cap \bigcap \{B_i : i \in I\}.
\end{aligned}

By induction, the result generalizes to the statement

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} A_{i, j} = \bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i, j}.$$

where $J$ is a finite set and $A_{i, j}$ is decreasing in $i$ for each $j$.